# What is meant by 'Commitments' for Evil Genius 2?

Tags: evil-genius-2

When I hover over the vault icon on the HUD, it breaks down my current cash and furthermore indicates future expenses in the form of 'Salaries' and 'Commitments'. Or at least that's what I think it's doing.

The Salaries component is intuitive (I guess I should pay these minions), but the Commitments is less so. At current, I'm not proposing any new construction, nothing is on fire that I haven't explicitly said should be, and yet I continue to have a never ending commitment to the tune of over $600k. Is there some minion getting scammed by Nigerian princes (if so, how can I find them and throw them into the volcano)? Alternately, does it have anything to do with items that I've specified are to auto-rebuild in the event they're destroyed (I've done this with nearly every camera because they're usually the first to go when fires break out).

If it's relevant, I noticed that the Commitments were vastly exceeding salaries last night following a base expansion. I'm not sure what the cost of the expansion was, but it might've been in the $600k range, regardless, once the construction's completed shouldn't that commitment clear?

Comment: There are a number of reddit posts that seem to indicate that this is an annoying bug.  The posts are from ~two years ago that I've seen, with some more recent comments saying its still a thing.

Comment: @TimmyJim I had seen those posts last night and was hoping that since that time there might have been some clarification on this that I wasn't finding.

Comment: Would it be possible that the commitments are related to some devious schemes or hidden costs that are automatically deducted from your funds. It could also be that there are ongoing maintenance costs for your base or equipment that you haven't noticed yet.

Comment: @artista_sin_nombre that's a reasonable assumption, but unlikely. My base is the definition of urban sprawl when it comes to underground lairs and the number seems to change and has been $0 before. Also, I don't recall any discussion of ongoing maintenance costs in the tutorial.